# How to learn a Normalizing Flow with Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sgd

I'm recently working on implementing the Annealed Flow Transport Method as described in https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.07501. At one point the task is to minimize a given loss function by learning a Normalizing Flow using SGD. I studied many papers on the several topics this problem brings with it, but can't figure out how to connect the ideas. So, here's the problem:

Suppose we are given a sample (x_1,...,x_N) of a distribution p. We now want to learn a Normalizing Flow T that transports each particle so that (T(x_1),...,T(x_N)) is an appropriate sample of the target distribution q. As described in the already mentioned source, this is done by minimizing the Kullback-Leibler-Divergence of T(p) and q. The resulting loss function (the one we want to minimize) is labeled with L or L(T).

The authors describe their algorithm quite detailed, however at this point they just say "Learn T using SGD to minimize L".

My intention was to use TensorFlow and Keras, with using L as a custom loss function and - as the authors suggest - the Adam optimizer, but, as it stands, here is my code:

```
def LearnFlow_Test(train_iters, x_train, W_train, x_val, W_val):
    
    # Initialize
    
    identity = lambda x: x # Initialize flow
    flows = np.array(identity)
    
    y_true = np.array([f_target(identity(x)) for x in x_val])
    y_pred = np.array([f_initial(x)/jacobian_det(identity,x) for x in x_val])
        
    val_losses = loss_function(y_true, y_pred)
    
    # Learn
    
    for j in range(train_iters):
        
        # Compute training loss
        
        y_true = np.array([f_target(identity(x)) for x in x_train])
        y_pred = np.array([f_initial(x)/jacobian_det(identity,x) for x in x_train])
        
        train_loss = loss_function(y_true, y_pred)
        
        """        
        Update flow using SGD to minimize train_loss
        minimizing_flow =
        
        """         
        
        # Update list of flows & list of validation losses
        
        flows = np.append(flows, minimizing_flow)
        
        # Compute new validation loss and update the list
        
        y_true = np.array([f_target(minimizing_flow(x)) for x in x_val])
        y_pred = np.array([f_initial(x)/jacobian_det(minimizing_flow,x) for x in x_val])
        
        val_losses = np.append(val_losses,[loss_function(y_true, y_pred)])a
        
        
        
    return flows[np.argmin(val_losses)] # Return flow with the smallest validation error
```

I would be grateful for any advices, as my search for already existing code was not succesful.

Many thanks,
Christian